# Create user in AWS AppStream 2.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appstream

Is there any way to **programmatically** create a user in *AppStream 2.0* ?
Didn't find any help in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AppStream.html)

Instead of using the console, going to `User Pool` and do it manually.
I already have a User Store and want to synchronize it with AppStream User Pool (without Active Directory).

Answer (score 1):

You can surely do it, as its the most basic feature in terms of API.

You can user the [`createUser`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AppStream.html#createUser-property) method.

```
var params = {
  AuthenticationType: API | SAML | USERPOOL, /* required */
  UserName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  FirstName: 'STRING_VALUE',
  LastName: 'STRING_VALUE',
  MessageAction: SUPPRESS | RESEND
};
appstream.createUser(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For larger AppStream deployments AWS recommends to use a SAML2 identity federation (no user sync). Alternatively you can use the API to create a streaming URL via a custom build application / script.

From: [AppStream 2.0 User Pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream2/latest/developerguide/user-pool.html)

> By default, AppStream 2.0 user pools support a maximum of 50 users. For deployments that must support 100 or more AppStream 2.0 users, we recommend using SAML 2.0.